# Переопределение onResume в классе Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Есть `BefFragment extends DialogFragment`, в котором переопределен метод `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int userDisplayWidth = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int userDisplayHeight = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int width = Constants.BEF_WIDTH *userDisplayWidth/ Constants.DISPLAY_WIDTH;
    int height = Constants.BEF_HEIGHT *userDisplayHeight/ Constants.DISPLAY_HEIGHT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
}
```

Есть `class Fragment extends BefFragment` , в котором метод `onResume` должен быть таким, как в классе `DialogFragment`, а не таким, как в классе `BefFragment`, т.е. в это методе не должны изменяться параметры контейнера диалога (ширина и высота). Как это сделать?

Пробовала переопределить в классе `Fragment` метод `onResume` так:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

проблема не решена.

Дело в том, что класс `BefFragment` и класс `Fragment`  используют один и тот же layout-ресурс для разметки, но в первом случае layout занимает почти весь экран, а во втором встроен в активити, где занимает 1/10 экрана. И, если метод `onResume` в классе `BefFragment` не переопределять, тогда окно `BefFragment`   слишком большое и не помещается на экран, а, если переопределить и рассчитать размеры контейнера для фрагмента, как я написала, то тогда возникает проблема с формированием layout, который содержит экземпляры класса `Fragment`: ошибка `NullPointerException` со ссылкой на строку

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

в `BefFragment` и на `super.onResume();` в самом `Fragment`.

Comment: что то мне подсказывает что вы не очень корректно используете возможности наследования

Comment: ну а как вы предлагаете поступить? Есть активити, в которое вложено 10 фрагментов, при клике на любой фрагмент появляется диалоговое окно (DialogFragment)с содержимым фрагмента, только "на весь экран". Т.е. разметка у фрагмента и у диалога одинаковая, разные только размеры ну и + методы диалога. Чтобы не переписывать кучу кода, я создала DialogFragment с нужной xml разметкой, а Fragment, которыми заполнен активити, сделала наследником DialogFragment. Т.к. последний является наследником Fragment, то проблем не возникло, все работает отлично. В чем неправа?

Comment: Тут дело не в неправы или правы, дело в том что можно сделать гораздо проще и лаконичнее без использования наследования как такового. Ваш кейс, имхо, можно было бы сделать проще и красивее (для конечного пользователя конечно, если вы этого не сделали). Но это уже отдельный разговор отличающейся от первоначальной темы

Comment: хорошо, если я задам отдельный вопрос, Вы поделитесь своими мыслями насчет улучшения моего кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заведите метод-флаг (возвращает `boolean`) внутри `BefFragment` с дефолтным значением, например, `true`, который Вы переопределите внутри `Fragment` и станете возвращать значение `false`. Внутри метода `onResume` в `BefFragment` делайте проверку. Должно получиться примерно это:

**BefFragment**

```
protected boolean checkPassed() { //примерное название метода
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPassed()) {
        // тут ваш код
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
@Override
protected boolean checkPassed() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: да, действительно, решение оказалось простым, просто думала "ни в том направлении". Я сделала немного по-другому, создала переменную boolean setWidthHeightParams; в методе onResume  if(!setWidthHeightParams) {// задается ширина и высота} а в методе onCreateView Fragment-а указала setWidthHeightParams=!setWidthHeightParams;

Comment: @VolhaGomel При пересоздании вью для фрагмента (ситуация когда мы возвращаемся во фрагмент из back stack'a) сделает второй, третий итд реверс переменной и в `onResume` будет не то поведение, которое вы ожидаете. Лучше в `onCreateView` устанавливать определённое значение, а не инвертировать текущее

Comment: понятно, я учту